# Not getting expected campaign IDs when using Facebook Ad Report Stats API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I created an access token with my personal account with additional ad_management permissions. I used curl to exchange this short-lived token for a permanent access token.

The roles page for my ads account says "You can manage campaigns, view reports, and view billing information."

I use this access_token with curl to get the offsite_conversions count from yesterday. The results contain data for a few campaigns. However these campaigns are nowhere to be found in the campaigns list in the ads manager. If I click a campaign and replace the ID in the url with one of the campaign ids int he response I get a "This content is currently unavailable" error page.

Additionally there are at least three campaigns shown in the ads manager's campaign list which do have a few offsite conversions recorded which are not showing up in the response of the Ad Report Stats API call.

How can I get more information to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was confused by the relatively recent change in the ad campaign terminologies. The reporting api is still using the old terms where a campaign corresponds to what is now an ad set.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match the campaigns in the ads manager with the campaigns you can fetch with the marketing api I would recommend you add ?fields=name. If you don't recognise the names, then there is probably something wrong :-)